# Override an export from another library es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given a javascript library (let's say `supportlibrary`) which has 100 named exports, I want to create my own `compat-library` which exports all named exports from `supportlibrary` but override a single named export with another.

For now, I can export all 99 named exports manually, but this would be a tedious job. I rather would have something like:

```
import {SupportComponent as ExcludedSupportComponent,...rest} from 'supportlibrary';
import SupportComponent from './MySupportComponent';

export {
    ...rest,
    SupportComponent
}
```

Is something like this possible using es6 / tc39-stage-x functionality? or is this only possible with `CommonJs`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
export * from 'supportlibrary';
export {default as SupportComponent} from './MySupportComponent';
```

to re-export all of the exports from `'supportlibrary'`, then export one additional named property that will take precedence over the `export *` version.

Comment: The OP's use case is to *override*, not supplement. Is the above in-spec when `SupportComponent` is one of `supportLibrary`'s named exports? (It works, at least on Chrome, but that's not the same as it being in-spec... :-) ) It's just, normally, duplicate exports are an error.

Comment: @Bergi Statically known duplicates cause errors, and if there are two different exports with the same name from `export * from`, it's "ambiguous" and thus an error, but as far as I know this approach just means it'll find `SupportComponent` and thus stop searching through that piece of the graph. See `ResolveExport`: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-resolveexport it checks indirect exports first and defers to them. I don't see any other errors that indicate it isn't purposeful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ^^

Comment: The OP's case would look more like this: https://pastebin.com/uKfnf89c  I haven't wrapped my head around the details of the spec's import/export stuff, but are we sure that use case is in-spec? (I haven't yet had the pleasure of wading deep into that part of the spec.)

Comment: As far as I know, it's valid. For my example, I was assuming `MySupportComponent.js` would just import `MySupportComponent` from `supportlibrary` separately, but yeah there are a few ways to do it.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks a lot (I can confirm the explanation)